# Python How to get location time in windows

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm new in python windows winapi.

How to get an location time from winapi using python
so the result time is like 
   `(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)`

I have tried using `win32api.GetTimeZoneInformation()` but the result just an number `(1, (480, u'Pacific Standard Time', <PyTime:11/1/2000 2:00:00 AM>, 0, u'Pacific Daylight Time', <PyTime:3/2/2000 2:00:00 AM>, -60))`

sorry for noob & bad question.

Comment: I like the answer from @pp_ that doesn't use any third-party packages, however I also notice that the actual [Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) recommends using the third-party `pytz` package.

Comment: I want get result like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112419/getting-windows-time-zone-information-c-mfc?rq=1) in python, in there using c++  I don't know about c++.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Python [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module:

```
import time

utc_offset = time.strftime('%z')
tz_name = time.tzname[0]

print('(UTC{0}) {1}'.format(utc_offset, tz_name))
```

Comment: `tzname` may be corrupted mojibake depending on your system locale, current preferred thread language, and current thread locale when `time` is first imported. With Japanese as the preferred language in the default C locale, the value of `tzname` in the UTC timezone is `'\x8b\xa6\x92\xe8\x90￠\x8aE\x8e\x9e'`, which is the ANSI (CP932) encoding mistakenly cast as a Unicode string. I have to first set the thread `LC_CTYPE` locale to Japanese to get the correct string, `'協定世界時'`. It would be better to use the Windows Unicode API directly via ctypes instead.